# add python dependency for XBMC addon

Tags: python, xbmc

i'm developing a XBMC addon that needs python Mechanize module. how can i add it as a dependency so while addon is beeing installed, the module gets installed too, so user don't need to install it using for example:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mechanize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `<import addon="script.module.mechanize" version="0.2.6"/>` to your "requires" block in your addon.xml.

Here are the docs: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Addon.xml#.3Crequires.3E

Keep in mind that requirements will only be resolved while installing an add-on. If you are just adding it to the addon.xml for an already installed add-on it won't get resolved automatically. I recommend to install any other add-on with same dependencies to get them resolved.

Btw, I am the maintainer of the XBMC packaged mechanize add-on.